When sailors were marooned on a deserted island, what were the odds of survival?
I recognize this is a difficult question to get data on because of survivorship bias. However many of the famous maroonings listed on Wikipedia were people who were rescued, and this is making me doubt how deadly this practice truly was.
Did this occur often enough that we can estimate the odds?

The Wikipedia list is 6 maroonings long. It's not going to be a representative survey of the fatality rate.

I don't think there can be odds without further clarifications to the specific case. Marooning was often thought of as a death sentence without "dirtying" the hands of the crew, or to restore the unity of the remaining crew after a mutiny. In the latter case, it would be intentionally survivable, in the former case, not.

@Spavel, I'm well aware of this, that's why I mentioned survivorship bias in order to get ahead of this discussion. I haven't found many sources on this, so I am coming here for help.

From a purely statistical point of view, this is fiendishly difficult because we know neither the denominator nor the numerator.  We could estimate, but there is a far more serious problem. The verb "to maroon" implies an intentional act.  It includes those who maroon shipmates with the intent that they not be rescued, but also to maroon shipmates with the intent that they be rescued. These are very different acts and should be treated differently.  Are those who maroon others likely to record the fact? or are they likely to list them as "lost at sea" with no further explanation.

"marooned on a deserted island" is a 17th/18th century equivalent of a meme, just like European noblewomen enslaved in a Turkish harem, or heirs to a throne raised in secrecy by a swineherd. The answer to the question "how often did that happen?" is simply: Scores less than the number of contemporary novels with that plot line.

@ccprog I think your claim requires some statistical support, even if it sounds plausible. However, I suspect that bastard children raised in obscurity were commonplace.
